# problems with <UL> and <LI> styling witout fixed witdh

Tags: css, positioning, html-lists

I am trying to create a list that will float on the right side of an image.
So first of all to understand  better, here is the fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/xpGbD/1/

Both the list and the image are contained inside a mutual DIV that floats.
What I am aiming for, is for the list to have a Key:Value pair, but some of the values are much longer than others.

This produces a problem, that when the value is greater than (DIV) - (Image) , the list jumps ABOVE the image, UNLESS I specify a fixed width for the list when floats right.

The problem is - I do not have a fixed IMG width , so if the width of the image is 100px for example, this will produce a large gap between the list and the image.

On the other had - if I fix a width on the LI elements , it will work, but will break if the image´s width will become bigger...

So the questions is :

How do I float the LIST elements to the right of the image without specifying width ??

Ps - another related problem : 
at the current state - When a list VALUE is long , the key is positioned ABOVE the value. I would like it to start on the same line, and if needed to flow , flow below the VALUE areaa ,and not the key area (hence the )

Comment: I think putting the img in the HTML before the list and then floating the img instead of the list will work.

Comment: @Mr Lister - when I try that - it just reverses the problem, and the list will jump BELOW the image, instead of ABOVE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me see if I've got the point...
When you try to float HTML elemets with unknown width, set the CSS property

```
display: inline;
```

To all floated elements.

Note that, the elements with different widths will not have an arranged grid view (table view)
If you want a table view : then you should specify width or use Table tag.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean . Putting `display: inline;` on all elements does not resolve the float problem for me .. Maybe I am missing something. COuld you please demonstrate it on the fiddle I have posted ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer . But I have noticed two things - one is that the ORDER of the divs is changed (the image comes first) and the other , is that you have replaced the <DIV> with a <P> tag. the first is not really a problem, but the second might be ... can you please explain why you have changed the tags ? I have noticed that this solution does not work with DIV. Do you know why ??

Comment: Actually, i forgot about changing tags. I just was testing and i forgot to reverse them.. So, don't worry about Tag arrangement. The solution does not work for divs because DIVs are rendered in different way that other tags.. Also the default CSS property for DIV is: disply:block; changing this property didn't work with floating.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will try and use your solution with the <P> tag, although I would still like to know how to achieve that with a <div>. And by the way ? do you know how to resolve the SECOND part of the question ? meaning to distance the key: from the value: ?

Comment: Yes, try give a value for CSS margin.

Comment: Acually, I have found a solution to the whole problem as a whole. In the case illustrated, the right tags to use are <DL> <DT> <DD> ,and not <UL> <LI> ... the floats work with DIV, and the margins are a breeze..

Answer (score 0):

Fiddled with absolute positioning yet?

http://jsfiddle.net/k4Rh8/

Comment: Absolute positioning like you posted will float the list INSIDE the image , and not to it´s right side..

Answer (score 0):

You going have limit the max width of the images, what's the problem in resize few images? Anyway, when you click at the image it will appears bigger right? Maybe a light box... And there's no wrap with a fidex width at your content right now, try this way...

Take a look, there was no fixed width at the div headblock...

http://jsfiddle.net/xpGbD/11/

Try to resize the image and see if it works as you wish.

The one with the min-width:

http://jsfiddle.net/xpGbD/12/

Just to register, maybe cold help someone in similar cases.

Comment: thanks for the answer .. but - the max width of the image is only limited by the containing div. There is no problem to re-size "a few images" (currently 14,000) they are actually re sized on upload,  but this is a part of a system which receive user uploads, where image size is not fixed nor predicted. the problem is when the image is SMALLER than the max-size, not bigger... and the image does not appear bigger with a light box or anything, it is a part of a header title...

Comment: You said that " they are actually re sized on upload", so if the images have max and min height you going have to work with fixed width. Oh, wait, the system allows uploads of any image size and resize only if it exceeds the max width?

Comment: yes, it is re sized ONLY if exceed a certain limit in WIDTH (not height) there is no MIN-width, and no max/min height. the list must align to the right of the image if the image is 10px wide or 800px.. and the problem is the long text that might appear in any of the list items. anyhow i will now look at your update.

Comment: I edited the answer, take a look. And if you could limit a min-width it would be nice, creating standards to the site it would make him look real better, imagine amounts images with different sizes.

Comment: @ Erick - thanks again for replying . I really appreciate all the efforts. My question however, was how to AVOID defining fixed width to create a total liquid layout. giving the .headblock class a fixed width will push other divs out of balance (try to down-size the pane..) . It is actually the first time I had such a float problem , that in first glance seems very simple, but apparently , it is not ..

Comment: Even if you set a min-width to the headblock is going to be hard, as the images have different sizes... Well, if you find any solution please let me know. Sorry but I runned out of ideas for this one.